# Intuitive reason why a simple symmetric random walk is recurrent on $\Bbb Z^2$ and transient on $\Bbb Z^3$.

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, random-walk

Polya proved the following very well-known Theorem:

> A simple random walk on $\Bbb Z^D$ is recurrent if and only if it is symmetric and $D<3$.

Dropping simplicity (i.e. allowing jumps to non-neighboring states) leaves this result essentially unaltered, as long as the distribution of the increments is not too heavy-tailed (compare e.g. Theorems 5.4.8, 5.4.9, 5.4.14 in the [book by Rick Durrett](https://services.math.duke.edu/~rtd/PTE/PTE5_011119.pdf)).

I am familiar with common proofs of these results, and of course I am able to see why they work for which dimensions. However, the point of this question is that I'd like to understand these results better **on a purely intuitive level**.

In view of the law of large numbers (which is very intuitive in itself), it is clear that asymmetry ruins any chance of recurrence. Furthermore, adding dimensions provides more possibilities for the random walker to "get lost", as the probability of walking in "the right direction" decreases. This makes it very plausible that, in the symmetric case, for some $D_0\in\Bbb N \cup \{\infty\}$ we have recurrence in all dimensions $1\le D< D_0$ and transience for all $D\ge D_0$.

It just so happens that this is true and that $D_0=3$. But why? Why not lower or greater? What's so special about two- or three-dimensional space? Is there any geometric reason that makes this more graspable?

I'd be very grateful for any helpful answer!

Comment: This may be related. Fractal dimension of the graph of Brownian motion is $2$ (for $d \ge 2$). (Don't ask me, I don't know the detail). This is also the explanation I was told why QFT (quantum field theory) become free in $> 4$ dimension. The world line of two particles are two $2$-d objects and the chance for them to intersect becomes zero when $d > 2+2$. (Once again, I forget where I see that).

Comment: https://www.quora.com/Why-is-it-that-a-2D-random-walk-is-recurrent-while-a-3D-random-walk-is-transient

Comment: @asd: Thanks for your comment, but this is just an imprecise summary of a common proof. "The return-probabilities start being summable at $D=3$" isn't exactly an intuitive argument. It's a calculation, a relatively simple one even, but it hardly offers any deeper insight into the nature of this phenomenon.

Comment: I mean, my intuitive proof (which is nearly rigorous) is that by Borel-Cantelli, you return infinitely often to the origin (with probability 1) iff $\sum_n Pr(\text{return to 0 after n steps}) = \infty$, but $Pr(\text{return to 0 after n steps}) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}^d}$, where $d$ is dimension, since each dimension is independent, and for one dimension, being exactly at the mean of a binomial distribution is $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$. You might say this $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$ is a calculation, which is true, but there is some intuition behind it, namely that the support of a normal distribution is...

Comment: roughly $\sqrt{n}$ (this is what you learn in a basic stats class, that, e.g., 95% of population is within 1 standard deviation of mean), and each thing in the support is roughly (i.e. up to multiplicative constants) equally probable.

Comment: The fact that $\sum_n \frac{1}{n^{d/2}}$ diverges for $d \ge 3$ is a calculation and not a geometrically insightful fact I must admit. Maybe you should look at proofs that Brownian motion is recurrent only in dimensions 1 and 2. The proof (that I know) uses harmonic functions, and you might find some geometry there.

Comment: @mathworker21: These are exactly my thoughts. The reasoning is indeed mostly intuitive - until the point where it comes down to seeing when this series converges.

Comment: @MarsPlastic yea, try to understand the proof via harmonic functions

Answer (score 7):

A heuristic argument: The random walk in any dimension tends to stay in a ball of radius $\sqrt{N}$ for the first $N$ steps. In dimension $d$, there are roughly $c N^{d/2}$ points inside the ball of radius $\sqrt{N}$ (for some constant $c$). So, if $d \leq 2$, then it is likely that the $N$ steps of the walk will cover the whole ball and, if $d > 2$, it is unlikely.

---

Regarding why the walk stays in a ball of radius $N$: Let the individual steps of the walk be $s_1$, $s_2$, ..., $s_N$, so the final position of the walk is $s_1 + s_2 + \cdots + s_N$. Write $E$ for expected value.

We assume that the individual steps are vectors independently drawn from some distribution with $E(s_j) = \vec{0}$ (there is no drift) and $E(|s_j|)$ a constant. Then
$$E\left( (s_1 + s_2 + \cdots + s_N)^2 \right) = \sum_{i,j} E(s_i \cdot s_j) = \sum_i E(|s_i|^2) + \sum_{i \neq j} E(s_i) \cdot E(s_j).$$
The first step is linearity of expectation and the second is the statement that $s_i$ and $s_j$ are independent. But we assumed $E(s_i)=\vec{0}$, and the $s_i$ all have the same distribution, so this is just $N E(|s_1|^2)$.

We have shown that $E\left( (s_1 + s_2 + \cdots + s_N)^2 \right)$ grows like $c_1 N$, so we should expect $\left| s_1 + s_2 + \cdots + s_N \right|$ to grow like $c_2 \sqrt{N}$. Making this argument precise will require filling in the exact kind of random walk involved, but hopefully this makes it clear why we expect $\sqrt{N}$.

Comment: "So, if $d \le 2$, then it is likely that the $N$ steps of the walk will cover the whole ball" Really? If $d=2$, then you said $cN$ points inside the ball; you expect N steps to visit every one of those? I know $c < 1$, but still, $cN$ is large...

Comment: @mathworker21 I think that is a good point, but I don't have time to engage with it. In particular,  I suspect you are right that, even though each point is visited with probability $1$, the probability that every point is eventually visited is likely to be $0$.

Comment: I think it is true that with probability 1, every point is eventually visited. I think it is false that, with high probability, after $N$ steps, every point in the ball of radius $\sqrt{N}$ will be visited. That is, I think it will take many more steps.

Comment: @mathworker21 so is the answer false?

Comment: @MarineGalantin I think this answer is wrong/false for multiple reasons.

Comment: so should people downvote it? I believe the question is interesting, but this answer is weird.

Comment: @MarineGalantin you should @ me so that I get notifications for your comments. people should downvote; I downvoted. Also, see my comments above for a partial answer to the question